# How can I change values in a column without knowing how many columns I have in the dataframe in r?

Tags: r, matrix, iteration, mean

I have a matrix

`df <- matrix(c(9185, 3661, 9539, 4266, 9650, 3897, 9160, 4451), nrow = 2, ncol = 4)`

and I want calculate: (element - mean(by row))/ sd(by row) .
Ex: (9185 - 9383,5)/248,03 and substitute the result in a matrix. Like that:

`matrix(c(-0.80030564, -1.144503446, 0.62694, 0.553656, 1.074466, -0.482080851, -0.9011, 1.072928123), nrow = 2, ncol = 4)`

The problem is that in the real case I need to iterate and I don't know how many columns I will have, but they will be all the columns present in the df dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to do row-wise calculations on a matrix.

```r
df <- matrix(c(9185, 3661, 9539, 4266, 9650, 3897, 9160, 4451), nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
t(apply(df, 1, function(x)(x-mean(x))/sd(x)))
#>            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#> [1,] -0.8003056 0.6269397  1.0744658 -0.9010998
#> [2,] -1.1445034 0.5536562 -0.4820809  1.0729281
```

Also, `scale()` is a function that does the calculation you want

```r
t(apply(df, 1, scale))
#>            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#> [1,] -0.8003056 0.6269397  1.0744658 -0.9010998
#> [2,] -1.1445034 0.5536562 -0.4820809  1.0729281
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Fred, if this answered your question, please consider marking it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

If you are pursuing the speed, you can try define a customized "`scale`" function like below

```
f2 <- function(df) {
    (df - rowMeans(df)) / sqrt(1 / (1 - 1 / ncol(df)) * (rowMeans(df^2) - rowMeans(df)^2))
}
```

and you will see that

```
> f2(df)
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.8003056 0.6269397  1.0744658 -0.9010998
[2,] -1.1445034 0.5536562 -0.4820809  1.0729281
```

## benchmark

```
f1 <- function(df) {
    t(apply(df, 1, scale))
}

f2 <- function(df) {
    (df - rowMeans(df)) / sqrt(1 / (1 - 1 / ncol(df)) * (rowMeans(df^2) - rowMeans(df)^2))
}

microbenchmark(
    f_DaveArmstong = f1(df),
    f_TIC = f2(df),
    check = "equivalent",
    unit = "relative"
)
```

gives

```
Unit: relative
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 f_DaveArmstong 17.09756 16.78235 2.380846 15.04688 14.59606 0.2508871   100
          f_TIC  1.00000  1.00000 1.000000  1.00000  1.00000 1.0000000   100
```